# How can I log http requests which run via the @RestController?

Tags: spring-boot

I did the logging with an interceptor (Spring-boot), which also logged ALL requests, including those caused by the internal cronjob. This is too much information and not what I would like. So I only want to have those that run via @RestController, requests outside the app, i.e. all POST, PUT and DELETE.
Is there also an option in the interceptor area, or should I write my own service?

Thanks for help!

Comment: OK, I'll do this pro @Restcontroller so I'm in control. With HttpServletRequest all necessary data is available.

Comment: You can try using Aspects